# Continue promise.all loop if error caught in lambda node scenario

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise

I have a simple node script run in AWS lambda function.  Each promise is an AWS sdk call which can fail, but for the most part I want to ignore the failures and continue.

When I catch the error and just ignore it as follows, I get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error

```
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        callback(null, 'completed');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('aws errors!', err);
    });
```

Each promise is basically a `putScheduledUpdateGroupAction` call as follows

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        aws.putScheduledUpdateGroupAction(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

What needs to happen to ignore the AWS errors and continue without this rejection error ?  I need it to continue in a lambda situation, not stand alone node.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? Where does the error get thrown, exactly?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've added code for the promise created

Comment: You should use the promisified variant of the AWS call. Simply return aws.putScheduledUpdateGroupAction(params).promise().

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

To ignore any failed promise, using `Promise.all(promises).catch()` should catch everything.

**Original answer:**

If you want to ignore failures of specific promises (not all), you can put a `.catch()` handler in each one.

```
return aws.putScheduledUpdateGroupAction(params).promise().catch((err) => {
    // Log the error but don't throw.
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `Promise.all`'s `catch` handle it though? https://jsfiddle.net/oLz5bvpa/

Comment: thanks but I was hoping to fix my existing code before I change the call to `.promise()` for the moment

Comment: `Promise.all`'s `catch` should handle it without the need to put a `catch` in each one. Can you share a complete example @yoyoma? If you log the value of `err` in your `putScheduledUpdateGroupAction` handler function do you see anything logged? My guess is the error you are seeing came from somewhere else.

Comment: Right. `Promise.all`'s `catch` catches _everything_. Clarified it in my answer.